# Rack / Passenger fails on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger, dreamhost

I am new to Rails & Ruby and have been following the http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book and amy trying to deploy the demo app to my Dreamhost passenger enabled host and when I try to run the app if fails with:

`Ruby (Rack) application could not be started`

and the following backtrace (formatting the best I can):

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  in `exit'
1   /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler/setup.rb  10  
2   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `gem_original_require'
3   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    36  in `require'
4   /home/oilfieldx/oilfieldexchange.com/releases/20120108233024/config/boot.rb 6   
5   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
6   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
7   /home/oilfieldx/oilfieldexchange.com/releases/20120108233024/config/application.rb      1   
8   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
9   /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
10  /home/oilfieldx/oilfieldexchange.com/releases/20120108233024/config/environment.rb  2   
11  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `gem_original_require'
12  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb    31  in `require'
13  config.ru   3   
14  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `instance_eval'
15  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb  46  in `initialize'
16  config.ru   1   in `new'
17  config.ru   1
```

My environment.rb file has:

```
# Load the rails application
<br>require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
<br>DemoApp::Application.initialize!
```

My app runs fine on my local machine but just craters once I deploy it.  I am guessing I am missing a line in a config file or something to do with my gems from what I gather researching this.

Comment: having the same issue. any luck?

Comment: What Rails version does your app use?

Comment: 3.0.3 if I recall correctly.  I have 3.1.x on my dev machine.  Is that the issue?  I tried re-installing the 3.0.x version but `rails -v` still reports v3.1.x.  What is the trick to downgrade?

Comment: I have Rails 3.1.3 on my dev system and DH has 3.0.3.  Do they have to be the same??

Comment: It need up being the gem versions being mis matched. I had to basicly downgrade on my local machine to get it to work. I then tried spree on Dreamhost which was a nightmare. I switched to Heroku. Bit of a learning curve but WAY easier and built for rails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer ended up being Heroku :^)