# Changing gemets to be compatible with Passenger on Dreamhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm, bundler, dreamhost

I had another post started:

[Rack / Passenger fails on Dreamhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784150/rack-passenger-fails-on-dreamhost)

but after some digging I am thinking my gems are incompatible.  My Dreamhost Passenger uses Rails 3.0.3 and my dev system has 3.1.3.  I have been playing around with rvm and gem but I can't figure out how to force rails and v3.0.3 dependancies.

Can anyone confirm that this is my issue and if so where do I start?  I am sure I am missing something obvious but all my Googling has come up empty handed so far.

I am pretty new to Rails and the entire gem concept still hurts my brain and this is probably have the issue I have so far :^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to edit the passenger entry in your gemfile to this:

```
gem 'passenger', '3.0.3'
```

and then run `bundle update passenger` on your dev machine.

I would really highly recommend you look into using rbenv or rvm to install and manage ruby and gems separate from the system gems that Dreamhost has installed though. I'm not sure if that's outside their terms, but you should be able to install locally for your user. This will help you avoid the same problem with other gems in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will try that when I get home and look into rvm on my Dreamhost account. So if I have this straight a gem is essentialy a 'plug-in' for Ruby / Rails and my app has to have the same gem versions on my dev and production system?

Comment: While you don't _have_ to have the same gem versions in different environments, it's definitely a best practise. You might not notice any problems, but when they come up, they'll be a huge pain in the ass to debug. And yes - a gem is a packaged Ruby application or library. (from http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/1)